# IDOC segment SAP ABAP

Tags: abap, idoc

Hi an IDoc segment `z1esui` has two fields:

1. zzdeanqty
2. zzceanqty

I want these two fields which tables are fecting in sap ABAP

Comment: Could you please fix your question "`I want these two fields which tables are fecting`", it's not English.

Comment: You can go on `SE11` and do a use-case on structure `z1esui`.

Answer (score 1):

It is custom IDOC type with custom fields. Maybe you can try below alternatives:

- Location of this type usage
- Abap code scan